# Expected in flat namespace error on running

Tags: python, namespaces, setuptools, kivy

Whenever I try to run kivy from the command line, or try to install things like easy_install via their python script I get:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
```

It happened first when I tried to install the dev version of kivy from github. It also happens when I try to install setuptools for pip. Is there a way to reinstall python, it seems my distribution is broken.

Comment: It might be worth asking on the kivy mailing list, I'm not sure any of our osx users visit stackoverflow much, and I don't know what would give this problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same error since I moved from Mavericks to Yosemite... looking into it.